# Photos import facebook-php-sdk not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(

                'appId'  => '<key>',

                'secret' => '<secret code>',

                'cookie' => true

              ));

print_r($facebook);die;
```

Output of this is

```
Facebook Object
(
   [appId:protected] => <key>

   [apiSecret:protected] => <secret code>

   [session:protected] =>

   [signedRequest:protected] =>

   [sessionLoaded:protected] =>

   [cookieSupport:protected] => 1

   [baseDomain:protected] =>

   [fileUploadSupport:protected] =>
)
```

This problems occur in the end of October only as before that it always prints information of session. Then I call link `https://api.facebook.com/method/photos.getAlbums?uid='.$session['uid'].'&access_token='.$session['access_token']` and used to get list of albums.

This works fine for more than 8 months and suddenly from last month it stopped working.

Comment: A good secret is kept secret.

Comment: It would be smart to have Facebook issue new API keys for you. By including them in your source code they're now committed to the revision history of this question and will be available to anyone who has access to see the [edit-log](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13612002/revisions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had some troubles on our Facebook API a couple months ago too.

Facebook has **deprecated the REST API**, which you are using. It is very possible the feature you're trying to access has changed and is no longer supported.

**Source:** http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/616/

Switch to the new OAuth2.0 API to restore your features and future proof your application for awhile..

Here's the link to the new API documentation:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api

---

Oh, and in the future... Be sure to remove any API keys and secret codes from your posts. These would potentially allow someone else to use your credentials mischievously.