# Issue with facebook photo import

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have made an app to import photos from facebook. I have been using this since feb 2012.
But suddenly since the last 1 month it has stopped working. Instead of taking the user to my page url which I had mentioned in the app, it is not taking the user to the facebook login page. On checking, I found that the facebook link that gives a list of albums of a user is giving blank results. Has something changed in the facebook-php-sdk 1 month before? Or is it an issue of facebook authentication?

Comment: maybe have something to do with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612002/photos-import-facebook-php-sdk-not-wokring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written my comment in this thread

Click this below link and go through my comment. Perhaps it will help someone :)

[How to import photos from facebook into a website using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429100/how-to-import-photos-from-facebook-into-a-website-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

when facebook launched their new php sdk, the older version was automatically deprecated in october'12